# SSRS HTTP Error 503 (web portal is accessible, but reports not accessible)

Tags: reporting-services, http-status-code-503

SQL Server Reporting Services was running fine on my server until 2-3 weeks ago when I started getting "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable." messages whenever I try to open a report via the SSRS Web Portal URL.  I have no idea why this started happening.

I'm running SQL Server 2017, Developer Edition (14.0.3238.1), under Windows Server 2019.

I can open the SSRS Web Portal URL, but I can't open any of my reports.  This seems to be a common problem according to what I've seen on SO and elsewhere, but solutions that worked for others aren't working for me.  Here's what I have tried so far, without success:

1. Stopped then restarted SSRS service via Report Server Configuration Manager.
2. Renamed the Report Server Web Service and Web Portal Virtual Directories, saved them; checked to see that the VD URLs were correctly updated in rsreportserver.config
3. Changed the VD ports from 80 to 8080, saved them; checked to see that the VD URLs were correctly updated in rsreportserver.config
4. Tried #2 & #3 above together (i.e. renamed VDs and also changed the ports); checked to see that the VD URLs were correctly updated in rsreportserver.config
5. Renamed the VDs back to their default values, changed ports back to default 80 value; checked to see that the VD URLs were correctly updated in rsreportserver.config
6. Changed SSRS service from "automatic" to "automatic delay"
7. Upgraded to .NET Framework 4.8. (I've seen suggestions that upgrading to .NET Framework 4.7 fixes the HTTP 503 error. I was already running 4.7, so I thought I might as well try the latest version which is 4.8, but it didn't help.)

I also tried running SQL Server 2017, Developer Edition (14.0.2027.2), under Windows 10 on a laptop.  SSRS works OK on the laptop.  Specifically, I backed up the report server databases on the server, restored them on the laptop, then configured the report server database connection on the laptop using Reporting Services Configuration Manager.  On the laptop I can open the reports via the SSRS Web Portal URL, but I cannot open the reports on the server.  I have compared the server/laptop settings in Reporting Services Configuration Manager but I don't see any difference, apart from the respective server names.

I have not tried uninstalling/reinstalling SSRS because I've seen plenty of comments from people who have tried that, without success.

Comment: There will be something in the Windows Event Log (Application or System, I forget which) that explains why the application pool or site has been stopped. This should hopefully point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  I poked around with the Event Viewer, but didn't find anything helpful.  That's not too surprising though since I have next to no experience or expertise with Windows logs.

Comment: The relevant events will only be present at the point the application pool / site gets stopped. You'll need to restart whichever has ended up stopped, then try to load SSRS (so that it stops again) and then have a look at the Event Logs - it's that or try and grok back through the logs to find when it originally stopped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working by uninstalling then reinstalling SSRS.  [Of course it had to be that--given the remark in my OP: "I have not tried uninstalling/reinstalling SSRS because I've seen plenty of comments from people who have tried that, without success".]  Specifically, after uninstalling SSRS, I downloaded the current version of SSRS (version 15.0.7243.37714 published 01-Nov-2019) and installed it.  Then I ran Report Server Configuration Manager and verified all of my settings.  Uninstalling SSRS does not remove the ReportServer or ReportServerTempDB databases, so I was at least spared having to restore those.  I can now browse to and open my reports.  I still have no idea why I started getting those "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable" messages, which is unsettling--I'm worried about inadvertently clobbering something and having to go through all of this again.  I hope this helps someone else.